# Unexpected token when using npm run dev on NextJS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

The next app when I run the `npm run dev` command is giving an error as follows:

```
$→��m��mo�L�D��;�%g�?w��ŷ↓�▬��ovH0��a�5��*�ؒ��l͛�S�iy☺�r�O7����%L]��%��∟�hk
 ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\next learn\next-whatsapp\whatsapp-clone\node_modules\caniuse-lite\dist\unpacker\agents.js:5:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
```

I don't know why its happening. I have checked all of my code and I can't really find any problem. Also I tried running `npm i` and then `npm run dev` but that didn't work as well.
The app was working fine before but after night I stopped the localhost and closed the PC and now after opening it back again this problem is occurring.

Comment: `working fine before` - so it was working, you shutdown you PC ... then you started your PC, and now it's not working! So, nothing could've changed while the PC was off. I'd do a complete disk health check scan and a deep virus scan on your PC - as this indicates that some file was corrupted during shutdown or during startup.

Comment: @Bravo Yeah correct! It was working fine before. How can fix any corruptions in my drive? should i chkdsk?

Comment: no idea - that is not a coding question - you need a hardware guy for that

Comment: Also try deleting node_modules and re-running npm install.

Comment: good point - I admit I over reacted to that whole "I did nothing but something changed" story, which is never a good sign. if it is indeed a failing hard drive, deleting a folder and re-downloading everything that's in it should work without any issues at all

Comment: and also @Bravo

Comment: GIve it a rest already @Bravo. You've made your point. He should check the hard drive for hardware errors *too*, but screwy node_modules happen without anything as dire as a hard disk failure.

Comment: erm, huh? contents of node_modules do not self alter during shutdown or startup - the **only** thing that happened between *my code are working good* and *my code are broken*

Comment: Oh ... it's you!!! didn't recognise who you were - I finally get the "give it a rest" ... even though, not sure what it is you're referring to @seesharper - did you change your name?

Comment: @seesharper make just an answer to question so that I can mark it accepted

Comment: @seesharper so that others can also benefit from this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try removing the `node_modules` folder and re-running `npm install`. Somehow your node_modules folder is likely to have gotten corrupted. As Bravo notes, you should also check your hard drive's integrity as it could possibly have been caused by a hardware issue.

Comment: SSD's especially have a limited life span

Comment: Could also be caused by running a version of node not compatible with the current project dependencies. 

I had switched to `node 14` few days earlier when trying to run a project from 2021 then forgot to change back to `node 16` when I attempt to start up `next 13`.